# Help! Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 1

Tags: validation-rule

I trying to create a validation rule, but I'm getting an error

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 1

my formula is below. I don't want anyone with the  TI:GER User permission set to be able to edit the four Academic Programs.

```
AND(
    OR (
        $Permission.Scheller_TI_GER_User , 
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL (Academic_Program_name__c = 'Full-time MBA'),
            ISPICKVAL (Academic_Program_name__c = 'Evening MBA'),
            ISPICKVAL (Academic_Program_name__c = 'Executive MBA - GB' ),
            ISPICKVAL (Academic_Program_name__c = 'Executive MBA - MOT')
        ),
        NOT(
            (
                ISPICKVAL (Academic_Program_name__c, TI_GER_Program)
            )
        ),
        RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Academic_Program'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As we can take from [the relevant documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_ispickval.htm&language=en_US&type=5)

`ISPICKVAL()` is not used like

```
ISPICKVAL(Academic_Program_name__c = 'Full-time MBA')
```

but rather like

```
ISPICKVAL(Academic_Program_name__c, 'Full-time MBA')
```

The first parameter is the picklist field
The second parameter is the value (and only one value at a time) you want to test against
both are required, and they *must* be separated by a comma

`ISPICKVAL (Academic_Program_name__c, TI_GER_Program)` is also a problem, because the second parameter needs to be a string. With the context that you've given us, I can't say what `TI_GER_Program` should be, only that it is not correct.

+edit:
Turns out that `Academic_Program_name__c` is not a picklist field, in which case using `ISPICKVAL()` is not appropriate.

Everything other than picklists (and multipicklists) is tested for equality simply by using `=`

```
AND(
    OR (
        $Permission.Scheller_TI_GER_User, 
        OR(
            Academic_Program_name__c = 'Full-time MBA',
            Academic_Program_name__c = 'Evening MBA',
            Academic_Program_name__c = 'Executive MBA - GB',
            Academic_Program_name__c = 'Executive MBA - MOT'
        ),
        NOT(
            /* The extra set of parentheses here accomplish nothing */
            /*   so they have been removed */
            /* Parentheses are used with functions and to specify */
            /*   a particular order that you want to do things in */
            /* That second usage only makes sense when they enclose */
            /*   more than just a single statement */
            Academic_Program_name__c = 'TI_GER_Program'
        ),
        RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Academic_Program'
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for you quick reply. When I change to ISPICKVAL (Academic_Program_name__c, TI_GER_Program) I got a new Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Text

Comment: @CodellGATech picklists are different from text fields. `ISPICKVAL()` is used with picklists. For plain 'ol text fields (that is, not textarea, longtextarea, or encrypted text fields), you just do the comparison directly (i.e. `MyTextField__c = 'some value'`)

Comment: It's a Formula (Text) field, should I use something other than ISPICKVAL()?

Comment: @CodellGATech Again, `ISPICKVAL()` is used for _picklists_ and _only picklists_. Everything else is just a plain, direct comparison.

Comment: Thanks for you help with this!! I was able to get it working with this formula.         AND( OR ($Permission.Scheller_TI_GER_User , OR (Academic_Program_name__c = 'Full-time MBA'))  ,   


NOT((Academic_Program_name__c = 'TI:GER Program')))